# What's the best way to run a small/medium java program from the command line?

Tags: java, linux, ant

Coming from a c++/make background, I'm used to doing something like this to build and run small/medium programs:

```
make
./foobar
```

However, with java/ant I'm finding I have to do something like this:

```
ant
java -ea -cp build/ foobar
```

Typing out `java -ea -cp build/ foobar` every time I want to test my program is pretty annoying, I'd much rather be able to do something simple like `./foobar`.

I came up with two possible solutions to this problem, but neither seems very good. The first is to just have the `compile` target create a file called `run`:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -ea -cp build/ foobar
```

And then just use `./run` to run the program, however this seems to go against ant's cross-platform nature, and also just seems like a bit of a hack.

The second option is to create a `run` target, for example:

```
<target name="run" depends="compile">
   <java classname="foobar" fork="true">
      <classpath>
         <pathelement path="${build}"/>
         <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
      </classpath>
      <assertions>
         <enable/>
      </assertions>
   </java>
</target>
```

This method also works, and seems a bit cleaner, but is incredibly slow! For example:

```
$ time ant run
Buildfile: /somepath/build.xml

init:

compile:

run:
     [java] /* program output */

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second

real    0m2.683s
user    0m2.548s
sys     0m0.136s
```

The above is almost 20 times slower (!) than this:

```
$ time ./run
/* program output */

real    0m0.143s
user    0m0.124s
sys     0m0.020s
```

So is there a better/more standard way of running a small/medium java program from the command line? Or should I just use one of the methods I posted here?

Comment: I tend to just write the command out longhand, and after that rely on my shell's history to run it again. `<control>-r foob<return>` should get me there. Doesn't help any actual users, i admit.

Comment: If you want to run a program quickly, I would run it from an IDE. This give you the option of seeing compiler errors as you type and `Run` or `Debug` with one click of a button.

Comment: I'm not an Ant expert, but Gradle has an [application plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) that supplies a `run` task which runs the program, as well as an `installApp` task, which creates platform-specific start scripts. There may well be an Ant equivalent.

Comment: @TomAnderson That's more-or-less what I've been doing so far, although I must admit that `<control>-r` trick is new to me, so thanks for that :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Fair enough I guess - I'm using the command line mostly because I find it's a better way to learn and understand the build process, so I'm staying away from IDEs for now.

Comment: @GordonBailey The command line will teach you the hard way. Once you have learnt to use a build system like maven and a good IDE, you won't want to do it ever again. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you want to build/run during development phase.

If so, then get an Eclipse and use it to debug/run, it's the most effective way of developping under java.

Usually:

- Ant is used for packaging phase
- shell is used for running program, and you would write one per environment (Linux/Windows/Mac OS)

Comment: It seems like this is probably the correct answer. I'm using the command line mostly to learn the java compilation process, and I guess there's just not any cleaner way to run a program than what I suggested in my question. I'll accept this answer if there are no others in the next couple hours.

Comment: It's a common way to provide different shell scripts for different OSes. You can also make the generation of these shell scripts a part of your ant build file.

Comment: @GordonBailey couple of hours have passed :-)

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE And now a couple of days have - my bad!